# Canvas "house" not appearing as expected

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>oppg.5</title>
   </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>


    <script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    c.canvas.height = window.innerWidth;
    c.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var cX = canvas.width / 2;
    var cY = canvas.height / 2;
    var blue = "#447FFF";
    var white = "#FFF";

    // house body
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(cX - 100, cY - 50, 200, 200);
    c.fillstyle = blue;
    c.fill();
    c.closePath;

    //window
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(cX - 70, cY -20, 40, 40);
    c.fillstyle = white;
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();

    // roof
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(cX - 100, cY - 50);
    c.lineTo(cX, cY - 50);
    c.lineTo(cX - 100, cY - 50);
    c.lineTo(cX - 100, cY - 50);
    c.fillStyle = blue;
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();

    // roof decor
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo((cX - 70) + (i * 20), (cY - 50) - (j * 20));
        c.lineTo((cX - 80) + (i * 20), (cY - 60) - (j * 20));
        c.moveTo((cX - 110) + (i * 20), (cY - 50) - (j * 20));
        c.lineTo((cX - 90) + (i * 20), (cY - 70) - (j * 20));
        c.strokeStyle = white;
        c.stroke();
        c.closePath();
      }
    }

    // body decor
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo((cX - 100) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j * 30));
        c.lineTo((cX - 130) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j * 30));
        c.lineTo((cX - 130) + (i * 30), (cY + 150) - (j * 30));
        if (j != 6) {
          c.moveTo((cX - 115) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j*30));
          c.lineTo((cX - 115) + (i * 30), (cY + 120) - (j * 30));
          c.lineTo((cX - 85) + (i * 30), (cY + 120) - (j * 30));
          }


          c.strokeStyle = white;
          c.stroke();
          c.closePath();
        }
      }


      // chimney
      c.beginPath();
      c.rect(cX + 60, cY - 120, 20, 50);
      c.rect(cX + 50, cY - 130, 40, 10);
      c.fillStyle = blue;
      c.fill();
      c.closePath();

      // window lines
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(cX - 70, cY);
      c.lineTo(cX - 30, cY);
      c.moveTo(cX - 50, cY - 20);
      c.lineTo(cX - 50, cY + 20);
      c.strokeStyle = blue;
      c.lineWidth = 2;
      c.stroke();
      c.closePath();

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q5kwv5s1/

I expect a house, but a wall is appearing instead. I don`t get any console errors. I follow this example: http://codepen.io/kratka/pen/YywpXV. I expect a blue house, bue a black wall is appearing instead. What am I missing/ doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a lot small bugs

first:

```
c.canvas.height = window.innerWidth;
c.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

u write c.canvas.height twice

second:

```
c.fillstyle = blue;
```

should be cammelcased fillStyle

third:

```
c.closePath;
```

c.closePath() is a function

4th:

```
c.fillstyle = white;
```

c.fillStyle again

5th:

```
c.lineTo(cX, cY - 50);
c.lineTo(cX - 100, cY - 50);
```

50 instead 150 and - instead of +

For more use: https://www.diffnow.com/

Comment: That was really helpful!